# Bootstrap carousel images not sliding or switching and controls (& indicators) are also not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am new to bootstrap and i got problems using carousel.

The images are not sliding or switching just stands in first image and the controls,indicators are also not working

I'm also new to stackoverflow so please excuse if my format is wrong.

---

Code as given below:

### head

---

```
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
          })
        });
      </script>
    </head>
```

---

### body

---

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="height:500px;">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Chania">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="Chania">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="Flower">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I almost solved every solution given for this carousel and can't make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check bootstrap.min.js and jquery.js links path. Otherwise try by adding cdn links

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me .but can i know why old path dint work properly

Comment: may be filename or linkpath is incorrect. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

add jQuery before bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey,i tried this above solution but problem din't get solved.can you make it again and help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add jQuery before bootstrap.min.js like this:

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
          })
        });
      </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: I tied your suggestions but problem din't get solved.can you make it again and help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `;` in your carousel script (4th line of the script)

Here you go:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I tied your suggestions but problem din't get solved.can you make it again and help me thanks.